# Does Google Pay Calculate Sales Tax?

Tags: javascript, google-pay

When implementing google pay, do you need to manually calculate sales tax and supply it to the api, or does the google pay api take care of this for you?

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate it yourself and supply it to the API.

Here is an example of how to do construct the request: https://jsfiddle.net/mqbhfrk9/1/

```js
function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    displayItems: [
      {
        label: "Subtotal",
        type: "SUBTOTAL",
        price: "11.00",
      },
      {
          label: "Tax",
          type: "TAX",
          price: "1.00",
        }
    ],
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: "USD",
    totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
    totalPrice: "12.00",
    totalPriceLabel: "Total"
  };
}
```